# asyncio: Is it possible to release control of the event loop without using yield from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am wondering if there is any way to release the asyncio control loop for a period of time in a function without having to use a coroutine decorator and the yield from keywords?

```
import asyncio
import time


class MyClass(object):

    def do_something_periodically(self, delay, repeats):
        for i in range(repeats):
            # Do something useful
            self._sleep(delay)

    def _sleep(self, delay):
        time.sleep(delay)


class MyAsyncioClass(MyClass):

    def _sleep(self, delay):
        # Perform an asyncio.sleep(delay) here which yields control of the event loop
        # and waits for time delay before returning


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
obj1 = MyAsyncioClass()
obj2 = MyAsyncioClass()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(
    [obj1.do_something_periodically(1000, 3),
     obj2.do_something_periodically(2000, 2)]))
```

I want to be able to do this so that the do_something_periodically method can be called from code which knows nothing about asyncio, but will release the loop control for the duration of the sleep. Is this possible?

Thanks!

**Edited** to show a cut down version of my particular use case

Comment: It is a design-smell if you can't find your use case in the `asyncio` documentation. You are likely to get better answers if you update the question to ask more about your problem and less about your proposed solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just isn't how `asyncio` works. It uses an *explicit* asynchronous model - if code is going to return control to the event loop, it either has to use `yield from`, or it has to use callbacks/`Futures`. If you're inside of a function (like `do_something_periodically`), you can't return control to the event loop without 1) using `yield from` 2) exiting the method altogether. You can do some amount of code re-use with the `asyncio` and non-`asyncio` versions of you classes, but any method that will need to call a `coroutine`, must also be a `coroutine` itself:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def do_something_periodically(self, delay, repeats):
        for i in range(repeats):
            self.do_something_useful()
            self._sleep(delay)

    def _sleep(self, delay):
        time.sleep(delay)

    def do_something_useful(self):
        # Do something useful here, which doesn't need to yield to the event loop

class MyAsyncioClass(MyClass):

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def do_something_periodically(self, delay, repeats):
        for i in range(repeats):
            self.do_something_useful()
            yield from self._sleep(delay)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def _sleep(self, delay):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

That said, it looks like your particular use-case can potentially be solved another way, but it looks little ugly, and requires changes to the `MyClass` logic:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def do_something_periodically(self, delay, repeats, i=0):
        while i < repeats:
            # do something useful
            if not self._sleep(delay, repeats, i):
                break
            i+= 1
        return i

    def _sleep(self, delay, repeats, i):
        time.sleep(delay)
        return True

class MyAsyncioClass(MyClass):

    def do_something_periodically(self, delay, repeats, i=0):
        out = super().do_something_periodically(delay, repeats, i)
        if out == repeats:
            asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

    def _sleep(self, delay, repeats, i):
        i+=1
        asyncio.get_event_loop().call_later(delay, 
                                            self.do_something_periodically, 
                                            delay, repeats, i)
        return False
```

We use `loop.call_later` to do the equivalent of an `asyncio.sleep`, and tweak `do_something_periodically` to support both completely iterating through the `while` loop for the normal use-case, but to also be repeatedly called with an increasing value for `i` in the `asyncio` case.

Unfortunately, there's no easy, sure-fire way to reuse the same code for both the synchronous and `asyncio` use-case. It's one of the major disadvantages of explicit asynchronous frameworks like `asyncio`/`tornado` vs. something like `gevent`, which uses an implicit asynchronous model. With `gevent`, `time.sleep(delay)` gets patched with a `gevent` version that will give control back to the event loop, until the `sleep` is complete, meaning no code changes are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I thought this was the case, but just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

I don't have control over MyClass (I can make a pull request ;) ), but I was hoping I could just replace time.sleep with self._sleep everywhere it was used in MyClass and it would just work.

As it stands I'll probably just copy paste the functions with time.sleep into MyAsyncioClass and try to keep it up to date with MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look [at the solution that is used by the Motor library](http://emptysqua.re/blog/motor-internals-how-i-asynchronized-a-synchronous-library/). Basically they use greenlets to "asynchronize" synchronous code.